# I need to access an item inside an array inside an array how to go about it (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Patient array inside of every patient there is a relatives array inside is an id and a relationship I want to show the relationship based on the id
here is an image for the data
[image]

```
 props.data.slice(0, props.n).map((item) => {
                    return (
                            <Grid item xl={4} md={4} xs={4}>
                                <Link to={`/patient/${item.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: theme.palette.text.primary }}>
                                    <Card boxShadow={3} key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.card }}>
                                        <CardImg src={item.imgUri} alt={item.name} onError={addDefaultSrc} />
                                        //here I want to show the relationship
                                    </Card>
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
   )
}
```

now to explain it more I have the for every patient a page and there are relative patient section the i render every paitent passed on the rletiveid now i already have the patient id stored now i wont to go throe all the relatives array and find where is == the patient id that i stored and return the relationshop the rletiveid should be unique it means every patient should return one relationshop

Comment: Need to explain *"based on id"* in more detail. Seems from a prior filtering question of yours you want `item.id` to match `relativeId` but that is an assumption that is not clearly stated in question

Comment: If my assumption is correct you could use `Array#find()` to get the correct object from relatives array. Also assuming that `props.data` is the outer array and each object has `relatives` property but that also isn't clear in question

Comment: @ charlietfl  no I don't wont the relativeId  to match item.id I already have the id some where else but it does not matter because the logic should be the same ... how can i use Array#find()

Comment: Ok well that just confirms that you need to detail this better so it is clear exactly what you need from what specific source using specific available information as well as defining exactly what `props.data` is so there is no ambiguity

Comment: give me a min i will try to explain more

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure correct as image, this should work

```
props.data.slice(0, props.n).map((item) => {
                    return (
                            <Grid item xl={4} md={4} xs={4}>
                                <Link to={`/patient/${item.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: theme.palette.text.primary }}>
                                    <Card boxShadow={3} key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.card }}>
                                        <CardImg src={item.imgUri} alt={item.name} onError={addDefaultSrc} />
                                       <p> {item.relatives[1].relationship} </p>
                                    </Card>
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
   )
}
```

Comment: I need it to be dynamic I don't wont to tell him to look in a specific filed I wont it to go throe the relatives array and find where the id match and then return relationship

Comment: I did not undestand anything from your answer